# Birational complex smooth varieties and homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$, $Y$ be two birational complex smooth projective varieties. Note they are also compact complex manifolds. I wonder if they are homotopy equivalent? If not, what topological properties do they share?  (I know they have the same geometric genus)

Comment: No, a blow-up of a point in, say, a surface $X$ is a connected sum with the complex-projective plane $CP^2$. (More precisely, the projective plane with the opposite orientation.) This changes $H_2$.

Comment: The fundamental group is a birational invariant. This thread on MO should be of interest: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33021/birational-invariants-and-fundamental-groups